# How to maintain WebSocket connections open after HTTP handler function returns?

Tags: go, websocket

I'm trying to write code to stream data on a topic, like a radio station (one broadcaster, several listeners). I'm stuck on how to process a new WebSocket connection request without having a goroutine for each open WebSocket (that starts to get resource-intensive for many "listeners" to the same "station").

At the moment, I have a map of dataStream structs which look like this:

```
struct dataStream {
  data chan byte[]
  conns []*websocket.Connection
}
```

And here's the pseudocode for upgrading the request to a WebSocket, and then attempting to add a WebSocket connection to the dataStreams conns:

```
func process_request(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // hundred lines of business logic...
  c := upgrade websocket connection
  defer c.Close()
  if dataStream exists {
    append the new connection c to the dataStream.conns slice
  } else {
    create new dataStream
    append the new connection c to the dataStream.conns slice
    stream(dataStream)
  }
}
```

And then here's the `stream` function mentioned in the above code block. One of these runs in the background for each dataStream (not for every WebSocket connection).

```
func stream(ds *dataStream) {
  ticker := time.NewTicker(poll every ~10 seconds)
  go func() { // this is to poll and remove closed connections
  for _ = range ticker.C {
    for traverse ds.conns {
      ping all connections, remove any closed ones and free memory
      if len(ds.conns == 0){ // no more connections are listening to this dataStream
        delete the ds dataStream and free the memory
        stop ticker
        return // kill goroutine and free the memory
      }
    }
  }}()
  while len(ds.conns) != 0 { // while there are open connections
    fetch any available <-ds.data from channel
    write the data as websocket message to each connection
  }
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that in the `process_request` function, as soon as the flow reaches the bottom `if statement` of the 2nd and subsequent connections, after the new connection is appended to the `dataStream.conns` slice the function terminates *closing the WebSocket connection!* As a result, `stream()` is running in the background and polls that a closed connection has been added to the `ds.conns` slice and removes it.

*Hence my question:*

What approach should I take to maintain the WebSocket connection open for even after the `process_request` handler function returns, preferentially without running a separate goroutine for each connection?

Comment: The `net/http` request handlers are meant for handling HTTP requests, not for managing WebSocket connections. Take a look at https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket for a standard library solution, or the library linked from that doc for a more complete third-party solution.

Comment: If you are using Gorilla, then returning for process_request will not close the connection.  Something else might close the connection, but return from handler is not the cause.  Because you don't share the actual code, it's difficult to comment on what might be wrong.  I suggest running the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) and fixing any issues reported by it.

Comment: @Adrian I am using the Gorilla library as recommended, and I was given to understand that it was normal practice to upgrade a http request.

Comment: @ThunderCat The actual code is about 750 lines, so I've used pseudo code. The problem is in the way the http request is handled and turned into a websocket connection, not the syntax itself (which compiles fine).

Comment: It's practically impossible to troubleshoot a specific issue with pseudocode. Please try to create a (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Adrian can you suggest a way of doing this with Go and Gorilla? That library can't be imported in the playground.

Comment: I'd be happy to try to trace down the issue, if I could see the code that produces it.

Comment: The application must explicitly close a Gorilla connection.  The connection is not automatically closed when the HTTP handler function returns.  Something else is going on.  Because you have 750 lines of code, I'd start with the race detector.  It might point to the problem.

Comment: @Thundercat. Thanks for the comment about Gorilla maintaining the connection open. I'll replace the pseudocode with a pared-down version that hopefully won't be too long so you might be able to see what's closing it.

Comment: Oh depressing;  I'm so sorry to have bothered both of you. @Thundercat you were absolutely right about Gorilla connection persistence. When I was trying to cut out the irrelevant fluff of the real code so I could post it, I noticed a `defer c.Close()` at the top of all the boilerplate connection creation code. Apologies for wasting your time. I've added that line to the pseudocode so you can at least create the answer and get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application must explicitly close a Gorilla connection. The connection is not automatically closed when the HTTP handler function returns.

In this case, the application uses a defer statement to close the connection on return from the handler.  Delete the defer statement to avoid closing the connection.